# Perl (or R, or SQL): Count how often string appears across columns

Tags: mysql, string, perl, r

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
gene1   gene2   gene3
a       d       c
b       e       d
c       f       g
d       g       
        h
        i
```

(Each column is a human gene, and each contains a variable number of proteins (strings, shown as letters here) that can bind to those genes).

What I want to do is count how many columns each string is represented in, output that number and all the column headers, like this:

```
a   1   gene1
b   1   gene1
c   2   gene1 gene3
d   3   gene1 gene2 gene3
e   1   gene2
f   1   gene2
g   2   gene2 gene3
h   1   gene2
i   1   gene2
```

I have been trying to figure out how to do this in Perl and R, but without success so far. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the columns tab-delimited, or are they space-formatted?  That will dictate how to treat them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution seems like a bit of a hack, but it gives the desired output. It relies on using both `plyr` and `reshape` packages, though I'm sure you could find base R alternatives. The trick is that function `melt` lets us flatten the data out into a long format, which allows for easy(ish) manipulation from that point forward.

```
library(reshape)
library(plyr)

#Recreate your data
dat <- data.frame(gene1 = c(letters[1:4], NA, NA),
                  gene2 = letters[4:9],
                  gene3 = c("c", "d", "g", NA, NA, NA)
                  )

#Melt the data. You'll need to update this if you have more columns
dat.m <- melt(dat, measure.vars = 1:3)

#Tabulate counts
counts <- as.data.frame(table(dat.m$value))

#I'm not sure what to call this column since it's a smooshing of column names
otherColumn <- ddply(dat.m, "value", function(x) paste(x$variable, collapse = " "))

#Merge the two together. You could fix the column names above, or just deal with it here
merge(counts, otherColumn, by.x = "Var1", by.y = "value")
```

Gives:

```
> merge(counts, otherColumn, by.x = "Var1", by.y = "value")
  Var1 Freq                V1
1    a    1             gene1
2    b    1             gene1
3    c    2       gene1 gene3
4    d    3 gene1 gene2 gene3
....
```

Comment: Thanks, always love an R solution, especially using the **ply functions.

Comment: you can simplify into a single `ddply` call by using `ddply(dat.m, .(value), summarize, Freq = length(variable), V1 = paste(variable, collapse = " "))`

Answer (score 6):

In perl, assuming the proteins in each column don't have duplicates that need to be removed.  (If they do, a hash of hashes should be used instead.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $header = <>;
my %column_genes;
while ($header =~ /(\S+)/g) {
    $column_genes{$-[1]} = "$1";
}

my %proteins;
while (my $line = <>) {
    while ($line =~ /(\S+)/g) {
        if (exists $column_genes{$-[1]}) {
            push @{ $proteins{$1} }, $column_genes{$-[1]};
        }
        else {
            warn "line $. column $-[1] unexpected protein $1 ignored\n";
        }
    }
}

for my $protein (sort keys %proteins) {
    print join("\t",
        $protein,
        scalar @{ $proteins{$protein} },
        join(' ', sort @{ $proteins{$protein} } )
    ), "\n";
}
```

Reads from stdin, writes to stdout.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the $hash{$-[1]} syntax. What's this doing?

Comment: `@-` is a special array that reports the position at which a regex capture started (`$-[1]` for where `$1` started, `$_[2]` for `$2`, etc.)

Comment: Special variable @- contains "offsets of starts of successful submatches in scope."  See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=353259.

Comment: oops, wrote %- where I meant @-; commment amended (and _ in place of one - and too late to edit it :( )

Answer (score 5):

A one liner (or rather 3 liner)

```
ddply(na.omit(melt(dat, m = 1:3)), .(value), summarize, 
     len = length(variable), 
     var = paste(variable, collapse = " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a lot of columns, you can do something like this in sql. You basically flatten out the data into a 2 column derived table of protein/gene and then summarize it as needed.

```
;with cte as (
  select gene1 as protein, 'gene1' as gene
  union select gene2 as protein, 'gene2' as gene
  union select gene3 as protein, 'gene3' as gene
)

select protein, count(*) as cnt, group_concat(gene) as gene
from cte
group by protein
```

Comment: err, but the hard part is flattinging out the data

Comment: Thanks. I've thought of doing it this way in MySQL but I have quite a few columns. I'll try this if I need to, maybe write some perl code to write my query, ugh.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, like so:

```
select protein, count(*), group_concat(gene order by gene separator ' ') from gene_protein group by protein;
```

assuming data like:

```
create table gene_protein (gene varchar(255) not null, protein varchar(255) not null);
insert into gene_protein values ('gene1','a'),('gene1','b'),('gene1','c'),('gene1','d');
insert into gene_protein values ('gene2','d'),('gene2','e'),('gene2','f'),('gene2','g'),('gene2','h'),('gene2','i');
insert into gene_protein values ('gene3','c'),('gene3','d'),('gene3','g');
```